# Alt+F2 doesn't display the Run Command Prompt in GNOME Shell

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I have *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS AMD64* and *GNOME Shell 3.4.1* and for some reason the `Alt+F2` keys stopped displaying the `Run Command Prompt` when pressed.

Now, I've seen the other answers that point you to setting the keys in the

- `All Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and
- the `Gnome Compatibility` in the `CompizConfig Settings Manager`

and they are all set. Still, the `Alt+F1` properly displays the `Activites`, but the `Alt+F2` just doesn't work (or it works, but the prompt doesn't display).

I've created a new account named `test` and it works ok in that one.

How can I reset the Gnome Shell to work properly w/o recreating the user?

EDIT 1:

Not even copying the `.gconf` and `.local` directories (and changing ownership) from the `test` home directory to mine worked. So it might be a problem of the shortcut keys working, but the prompt not showing.

EDIT 2:
When pressing `Alt+F2` the following shows up in the `~/.xsession-errors` file

```
  JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: Error: Error invoking Gio.monitor_directory: Unable to find default local directory monitor type
    JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '0'
    JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"gjs_throw"'
    JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"("Error invoking Gio.monitor_directory: Unable to find default local directory monitor type")@gjs_throw:0
()@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/runDialog.js:60
wrapper()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:204
()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:145
()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:239
()@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/runDialog.js:238
wrapper()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:204
()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:145
()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:239
getRunDialog()@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/main.js:799
([object _private_Meta_Display],[object _private_Meta_Screen],null,[object _private_Meta_KeyBinding])@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/main.js:140
"'
    JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Error invoking Gio.monitor_directory: Unable to find default local directory monitor type"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting `global_keybindings/%gconf.xml` this file (You can also edit this file),   for not working user. File contains key bindings for that gnome session.
Had same problem worked for me after deleting file and resetting Alt+F2 for the run command prompt in System Settings.

global_keybindings file would be present in `~/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybinding/%gconf.xml`

Steps to reset Alt+F2

Open  System Settings => keyboard settings window, navigate to Shortcut tabs and set the System > Show the run command prompt key with Alt+F2. To set the key, simply double-click on the list or for new key bindings right click the Show the run command prompt key and press new keys from keyboard.

Go to System Settings and click the “Keyboard” icon.

[image]

Click on the “Shortcuts” tab. On the left panel, select “System”. On the right, select the first entry “Show the run command prompt” and click on “Disabled” to activate it. You should now see “New shortcut…”
[image]

Comment: I already explained that it is already set with the question.

Comment: No I'm suggesting for resetting it, after deleting entry/file from global_keybindings/%gconf.xml file. Actually It worked for me, So i thought it'll work for you also, If that is not the case you can give some more info like what you tried, Is dmesg showing some error msgs.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I checked the error log, and I put it in the question (EDIT 2)

Comment: Did you know that you can actually edit the `gconf.xml` file with a friendly GUI named `gconf-editor`? For newer systems, there's `dconf-editor` too.

Answer (score 0):

Killing nautilus worked for me:

```
killall -15 nautilus
```

Then `alt + f2` started working again.